# constructor super() es6 angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, super

I have class AbstractRepository and class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository. I am declaring super() in my constructor but the error is _http is not defined. How can i insert $http in class UserRepository.

AbstractRepository:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

class AbstractRepository {
    _http;
    _config;
    _Model;

    constructor($http, config, Model) {
        'NgInject'
        this._http = $http;
        this._config = config;
        this._Model = Model;
    }

    /**
     * Gets all instances of repository entities
     * 
     * @returns {Observable<Model[]>} - List of observables of all entities
     */
    getAll() {
        const url = this._config.url;
        return this._http.get(url)
            .map(dataList => dataList.json())
            .map(dataList => _.map(dataList, item => new this._Model(item)));
    }

    /**
     * Gets a specific item of repository entity
     * 
     * @param {number} itemId - ID of an item to find
     * @returns {Observable<Model>} - Observable of repo entity item
     */
    getItem(itemId) {
        const url = this._config.url + itemId;
        return this._http.get(url)
            .map(item => item.json())
            .map(item => new this._Model(item));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a specific item of repository entity
     * 
     * @param {Model} item - Item to create
     * @returns {Observable<Model>} - Observable of recently created item
     */
    createItem(item) {
        const url = this._config.url;
        return this._http.post(url, item)
            .map(item => item.json())
            .map(item => new this._Model(item));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a specific item of repository entity
     * 
     * @param {number} itemId - ID of an item to update
     * @param {Model} item - Wanted updated item
     * @returns {Observable<Model>} - Observable of repo entity item
     */
    updateItem(itemId, item) {
        const url = this._config.url + itemId;
        return this._http.put(url, item)
            .map(item => item.json())
            .map(item => new this._Model(item));
    }
}

export {AbstractRepository}
```

UserRepository:

```
import { USER_REPO_CONFIG } from '../repository.config';
import { AbstractRepository } from '../abstract.repository';
import { UserModel } from './user.model';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository {
    _http = $http;
    constructor() {
        'NgInject'
        super(_http, USER_REPO_CONFIG, UserModel);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the user by ID
     * 
     * @param {number} userId - ID of a user to find
     * @returns {Observable<UserModel>} - User model instance
     */
    getUser(userId) {
        return this.getItem(userId);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the user
     * 
     * @param {UserModel} user - User model instance
     * @returns {Observable<UserModel>} - User model instance observable
     */
    createUser(user) {
        return this.createItem(user);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the user
     * 
     * @param {number} userId - ID of a user to update
     * @param {UserModel} user - User model instance
     * @returns {Observable<UserModel>} - User model instance observable
     */
    updateUser(userId, user) {
        return this.updateItem(userId, user);
    }
}

export {UserRepository};
```

Comment: What is `_http = $http;`? That's invalid ES6. And where do you think `$http` comes from?

Comment: I want to set standart angularjs $http to my class property

Comment: The random 'NgInject' string is cringeworthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to declare `$http` as a parameter of your child constructor if you want to forward it to the parent constructor:

```
class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository {
    constructor($http) {
        'NgInject'
        super($http, USER_REPO_CONFIG, UserModel);
    }
    …
}
```